# Creating PDF version from Docusaurus 2.0

Tags: docusaurus

I've tried using the PDF plug in from https://github.com/kohheepeace/mr-pdf bit it is not working for me. PDF generation takes forever.

Is there an alternative or maybe some crawler that I could run on live site to get the PDF version?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [docusaurus-prince-pdf](https://github.com/signcl/docusaurus-prince-pdf), this library relies on [Prince](https://www.princexml.com/) printing library, so make sure you have prince installed before using this tool.

Simply run this command in your terminal to start downloading your docusaurus pages into a PDF file.

```
npx docusaurus-prince-pdf --include-index -u http://your-docusaurus-site/docs/intro
```

The PDF file will be saved in <current_dir>/pdf

This tool requires NodeJS 16 or later